# Virtual Box Windows XP Image DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, crash

I am running Oracle VM Virtual Box 4.1.18 on a Windows 7 Machine and trying to start a Windows XP image. When it starts up it immediately crashes with the error DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL. I did a little research online and there were some suggestions that it had to do with the networking, so I disabled all of the network adapters and it still happens. (safe mode, normal startup, everything).

I know it is not a bad image because the same one works on my friends computers perfectly (I verified the MD5 checksum so I know my version isn't corrupted).

I run all sorts of Linux images all the time, its just this one image that my computer seems to have a problem with.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Running on Windows 7 computer, 6GB ram, 2.5GHz processor. If there is any info I didn't include that could be helpful please let me know.

Comment: Where did the VM come from? That stop code relates to hardware, not specifically NICs. Your CPU, motherboard (and all embedded stuff), video card, NIC, are all affected.

Comment: I actually just figured it out. I went through and tried changing all of the settings to get it to work. If I disable the USB driver on the XP image settings it boots up fine. I don' t think I will need the USB driver but is there any quick way I could fix that, or is it going to be a whole big issue?

Comment: The USB controller is driven (if you'll excuse the expression) from the original motherboard chipset drivers. You'll need to nuke those and install the VirtualBox tools to get USB working.